# Importing Excel having 2000 columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

I used OleDb for importing Excel file which is having 2000 columns. So by using this piece of code i can able to have only 255 columns in my DataTable. I want some other way or if possible this way to get 2000 columns to my DataTable.

```
DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();

 using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
 {

      con.Open();
      DataTable dtSheet = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
      List<string> listSheet = new List<string>();
      foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
      {
           if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$"))
               {
               listSheet.Add(drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
               }
      }

      string workSheetName = listSheet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(cCommon.sFDDetailsWorkSheetName));
      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", workSheetName.Trim()), con);
      cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
      OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
      dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
      dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
      }
```

Comment: Instead of data table try to use XML.

Comment: how will i  get excel file to xml object without using DataTable @PareshJ

Comment: You need to add loop to get each column and its data. I know its lengthy process but will definitely works.

Comment: Or you can use OPENROWSET if you have appropriate db access rights

Answer (score 1):

Using OleDb for accessing Excel is a possible way, but not the best. I suggest to consider using third party libraries for importing from Excel.

There are two very recommended:

- [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/), which is a .NET port of POI: Java API for MS Documents
- [ClosedXML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML), which a wrapper on top of OpenXML, which is a Microsoft open-source library for accessing Excel spreadsheets

Both are good and will do the job. In addition, they are free and do not require MS Office to be installed on the machine.